# Add image to RSS Feed

Tags: views, 8, hooks, feeds

We are using the `Feed` Display for a view where we want to display all `Articles` in a `rss.xml` file. Below are the View settings. However, we cannot find a way to add an image attribute that meeting the [RSS 2.0 specs](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html#ltimagegtSubelementOfLtchannelgt).

**How can we add an image to the `RSS` feed display?**

View settings:

1. Format: Rss Feed
2. Show: Fields | Settings
3. Fields: `content: title`, `content: body`, `tracker: updated date`, `content: link to content`, `content: authored by`
4. Feed settings: path = `some/path/rss.xml`
5. Filter criteria: `published = yes` and `Content type = Articles`

When you click on settings in the `Show` section, we assigned the fields.

1. title field -> content: title
2. link field -> content: link to content
3. description field -> content: body
4. creator field -> content: authored by
5. publication date field -> tracker: updated date

What we tried:

- Include `field_image` under `fields` and hide from display
- Rewrite the output of the body to include the following `<enclosure url="{{field_image}}" length="100" type="image/jpg" />`
- The `{{ field_image }}` is the available token after reordering field image under `Fields` section so that it is above `body` field.

Results of what we tried:

`<description>some body text  **blank space where <enclosure> should display** </description>`

Expected output (cannot get this result because `<enclosure>` is stripped even when `Strip HTML is false`):

`<description>some body text</description>
<enclosure url="{{field_image}}" length="100" type="image/jpg" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found there is a patch that works for exactly what we need. [Support enclosure field in Views RssFields row plugin](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2511878)