# How to create an RSS or Atom Feed in Drupal (source)?

Tags: 8, views, feeds

I have a website with Drupal 8 CMS and I have a second website without CMS.

I want to create an RSS or Atom Feed on my Drupal site (this will be the source).

I want to display the RSS or Atom Feed on the second site.

How to create an Atom or RSS Feed in Drupal 8 nodes to display it on the second site ?

Comment: Views has RSS support built in.  For example, see this tutorial: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/creating-rss-feeds-in-drupal-using-views/

Comment: @PatrickKenny Thanks, do you know if it is possible to add an image, or a rendered entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Views to create feed with content and fields you desire. A bit more up to date tutorial: https://yalesites.yale.edu/book/creating-rss-feed-views

Comment: Thanks, do you know if it is possible to add an image, or a rendered entity ?

Comment: @franky Try searching this site: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/276804/add-image-to-rss-feed

Comment: ViewsRSS module would help (and with a lot of other fields too), I used extensively in D7. But D8 version is still in dev as I see: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rss/releases/8.x-2.x-dev not sure if it will work for you.